# Which is more performant between set based operation vs lookup transform?

Tags: ssis

I am writing an ETL package that will read data from a csv file (ID,Name) and insert into a SQL table. If the data already exists in the SQL table (check based on ID column) then it will update the data.

I can read the file, pass the data to the lookup transform which will have the data from the SQL table (full cache mode) and direct the rows to the stage_tbl_inserts or to stage_tbl_updates, followed by the SQL query perform the insert/updates of the batch.

The other option is to stage the data from csv file, and then either use SQL merge, or SQL left join (where other column is null) approach to insert/update the data into the SQL table.

Theoretically the SSIS lookup compares **each row with the cached data (as it is a row-wise operation)**. Where as SQL merge or left join approach performs a SET based operation on entire dataset.

So which is more performant between set based operation vs lookup transform? Or does the answer depend on the size of the file data and the SQL table data?

Answer (score 0):

While you've provided some detail, this has many variables; table size and structure, indices in place for each table and their relevance to the transform.

In my experience with huge datasets, I'm better served by expending effort early on a test harness to capture timing of each stage.

Then, take an empirical approach, rapid iterations to optimise for a small dataset.  Then see what happens to the performance indicators as you scale.